# Insert text inside a image in eps format

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, eps, matlab

UPDATE:I tried the solution with overpic and it works fine. But the problem is, sometimes, my experimental setup changes and I have to reproduce the eps file using different parameters from Matlab. This results in me again re-adjusting the co-ordinates to align the tex code corresponding to the different objects in the image(eps format). This is difficult when I have to do it often. Is there any solution for that?

QUES: I have an image of solid rectangle generated in `eps` format from Matlab. Let us say, there is no other way for me to generate the same (I have other complicated things inside this rectangle). I want to mark the co-ordinates of the corners of this rectangle. Thus, I want to insert some text of the form

```
$(\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max})$
```

inside the image. The inbuilt editor of Matlab is not satisfactory. Is there any option in LaTeX to do the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20792/15717)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PSfrag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSfrag) is a LaTeX package that allows one to overlay Encapsulated PostScript ( EPS) figures with arbitrary LaTeX constructions. I know that it works for figure created with MATLAB but I forgot if there are any caveats. I very seldom use MATLAB to create pictures for my documents. I use PSfrag often with Xfig. It is included in most TeX distribution with exception of KerTeX.

Comment: it is useful!. I am waiting for other replies.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy problem. Overlaying a text on the existing EPS can be done as follows.

- Create a new input file just for overlaying the existing EPS. Use  `standalone` document class so we get a tight output (all white spaces outside are trimmed automatically). The following code snippet can be used as a template. The `border` key should be removed in the final stage.
- You need to change the `\filename` and `\scale` (if necessary).
- Specify the coordinate at which you want to put the label.
- Compile this input file with either `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (much much faster) or `xelatex` (much slower) to get a tight PDF output.
- Import the PDF output from within your main input file by using `\includgraphics` and compile this main input file with `pdflatex`.
- Done!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}% remove border key in the final stage.
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\filename{example-image-a}% change it to your filename
\def\scale{1}
\def\row{10}
\def\column{10}

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{\filename}}
\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\column,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\row,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\column,\row)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \psgrid% turn this grid off in the final stage.
    \rput(5,8){\color{red}\Huge$(\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max})$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the same possible in tikz?

Comment: @dineshdileep: No for EPS.

Comment: +1, really appreciate the effort, but not so useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using [overpic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic), assuming there is no tagged eps file to use with psfrag. [overpic relative example at ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/overpic/opic-rel.pdf).

Place the math labels at target locations with the help of overlay grid. Once math labels are set disable the grid similar to PSTricks answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\begin{document}
%\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth,grid,tics=10]{sphere-example}
% sphere generated from matlab % sphere; cpmmand
\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth]{sphere-example}
\put(0,15){\Large$\lambda_{max}$}
\put(40,-3){\Large$\lambda_{min}$}
\put(50,-3){\Large$\lambda_{min}$}
\put(98,10){\Large$\lambda_{max}$}
\end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

The [psfrag package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) 
replaces text strings (eg: `x`,`y` or tags) in tagged eps ﬁles. It is advisable to  generate tagged `.eps` with tags( small labels) at appropriate location so as to replace them with psfrag. Refer the [Guide to using Encapsulated PostScript in LATEX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) for more psfrag.

Related Question:
[How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20792/15717)

Comment: You can upload the picture for example in Xfig and create add text strings even if original picture didn't have one. There is a Unix package pstoedit which enables you to even convert eps figure into .fig format if you prefer that way.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac   Good to know, may be add [xfig,free(Linux)](http://epb.lbl.gov/xfig/installation.html) and [its cousin winfig,shareware(windows)](http://www.schmidt-web-berlin.de/winfig/) at [Tagging for PSFrag](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49478/15717) question. Also [Inkscape,free(cross-platform )](http://inkscape.org/) for adding text strings in eps.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac does it allow include heavy tex equations?

Comment: @dineshdileep I have not hit any limitations but I will admit that I didn't push things really hard.